# retrieve the id of one element through its css class

Tags: jquery, css

I have some elements which have the same CSS class

I would like to know how can I retrieve the ID of one of them; such as the first one with that class

This is my current code, but it isn't working

```
$('.imageofarticle').mousemove(function(){
  var a = $(this).attr('id');
  var tableau = a.split(":");
  alert("get the first : "+$('.showmovingEdit').[0].attr('id'));
  // $('.showmovingEdit')[tableau[1]].show();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have extra `dot` and calling attr on `DOM` object instead of directly accessing `id`

*Change*

```
$('.showmovingEdit').[0].attr('id')
                    ^
```

*To*

```
$('.showmovingEdit')[0].id
```

or using [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/)

```
$('.showmovingEdit').get(0).id
```

or using [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)

```
$('.showmovingEdit').eq(0).attr("id");
```

**Edit**

> Each jQuery object also masquerades as an array, so we can use the
>   array dereferencing operator to get at the list item instead: [Reference](http://api.jquery.com/get/)

```
alert($('selector')[0]); //gives first element returned by selector.
```

Comment: I have updated my answer, I think you are looking for indexer notation to access the DOM element, http://api.jquery.com/get/

Comment: ok, thank you the key word to get the reference is **get**; that 's all I needed ;)

Answer (score 3):

Your code syntactically is wrong, for selecting the first element you can use `first` method:

```
// Return the first element in jQuery collection
$('.showmovingEdit').first().attr('id');
```

For selecting other elements, you can use `eq` method:

```
// Return an element based on it's index in jQuery collection
$('.showmovingEdit').eq(index).attr('id');
```

Note that when `[index]` is used (*correctly*), it returns a DOM Element object that doesn't have `attr` method, you should use `id` property instead:

```
// Select the first DOM element in the set and return it's ID property
var id = $('.showmovingEdit')[0].id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use this:

```
$('.showmovingEdit').attr('id')
```

Also, referring to many other posts: You don't need `first()`. `attr()` will automatically take the first element if called without an argument.